# Appaccelator Titanium gives build to the user or the code?

Tags: javascript, titanium, rhomobile

I am new to the technology which is being used in the appaccelator titanium and other IDEs like this rhombile etc. I was wandering that after making the app what does this IDEs give to the developer? both the build and the source code or just the build? I'll appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building you have access to the `resources` folder where your javascript code is. You also have access to all the other compiled and none compiled code alike through the `build` directory and the various Titanium SDK such as `mobilesdk/iphone/1.7.0` would  have all the compile symbols Titanium uses to make your code native to the iPhone.

Comment: thanks for replying. I want to know that does the the user get the code generated using those javascript, i mean the code in objective c. And the .app build that the xcode gives us which is used for the distribution?

Comment: Yes it's all in the `build` folder after a build.